# Sort array of tuple over multiple indices, only one reversed in Julia

Tags: arrays, sorting, tuples, julia, reverse

I have an `Array{Tuple{Float64, Int}}`, I want to sort it in reversed order according to the first entries and in straight order according to the second one.

Example: if `a=[(1.0,2),(3.0,1),(2.0,3),(2.0,2)]`, after calling `sort!(a, ...)`, I'd like to get `[(3.0,1),(2.0,2),(2.0,3),(1.0,2)]` where the first dimension is sorted from greater values to smaller ones and, when two entries are equal, the second dimension is sorted from small to big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to customize the sorting order, using either the `lt` or `by` keyword arguments to `sort` (or `sort!`):

1. using `lt`: you define a custom "less-than" operator for tuples. You encode in this comparison operator more or less the order as you'd express it in a plain way:

```
julia> a=[(1.0,2),(3.0,1),(2.0,3),(2.0,2)];

julia> mylt((x1,y1), (x2,y2)) = x1>x2 || (x1==x2 && y1<y2)
mylt (generic function with 1 method)

julia> sort(a, lt=mylt)
4-element Array{Tuple{Float64,Int64},1}:
 (3.0, 1)
 (2.0, 2)
 (2.0, 3)
 (1.0, 2)
```

2.using `by`: you define a transformation that is applied to each element in the array, and by which elements are sorted:

```
julia> x_desc_then_y_asc((x,y)) = (-x, y)
x_desc_then_y_asc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> sort(a, by=x_desc_then_y_asc)
4-element Array{Tuple{Float64,Int64},1}:
 (3.0, 1)
 (2.0, 2)
 (2.0, 3)
 (1.0, 2)
```

The helper function in that variant is so short that I would make an anonymous function out of it:

```
julia> sort(a, by=((x,y),)->(-x,y))
4-element Array{Tuple{Float64,Int64},1}:
 (3.0, 1)
 (2.0, 2)
 (2.0, 3)
 (1.0, 2)
```

PS: note how "tuple destructuring" is used in all these examples in order to avoid indexing explicitly into tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify your own "isless" function for ordering, e.g.,:

```
julia> myisless(x,y) = (x[1]<y[1]) || (x[1]==y[1] && x[2]>y[2])
myisless (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a=[(1.0,2),(3.0,1),(2.0,3),(2.0,2)]
4-element Array{Tuple{Float64,Int64},1}:
 (1.0, 2)
 (3.0, 1)
 (2.0, 3)
 (2.0, 2)

julia> sort!(a, lt=myisless, rev=true)
4-element Array{Tuple{Float64,Int64},1}:
 (3.0, 1)
 (2.0, 2)
 (2.0, 3)
 (1.0, 2)
```

Or see Francois' answer which offers this and a smart alternative.